# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in Java program, and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm creating a program that's currently matching up elements of a String array to a String of user input, and the section I'm getting stuck on is if the user misspells an available word in the array, how do I spit out the closest suggestion (which, in the below program, is if six letters from the input share the same letters as one of the array elements)? This is the segment of code where I'm erring:

```
int t = 0;
LoopB: while (t < 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= langs.length; i++) {
        Scanner convLangs = new Scanner(langs[i]);
        while (! search.equalsIgnoreCase(langs[i])) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= langs[i].length(); j++) {
                while (convSch.hasNext()) {
                    String cS = convSch.next();
                    if (cS.equalsIgnoreCase(convLangs.next())) {
                        c++;
                        if (c == 6) {
                            System.out.println("Did you mean \"" + langs[i] + "\"? Yes or no?");
                            String confirm = console.next();
                            if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                                System.out.println(langs[i]);
                                break LoopB;
                            } else if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                                System.out.println("Please check the spelling of your search and try again.");
                                String redo = console.next();
                                search = redo;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the same error no matter what I do, and I've tried changing "<=" to "<" in the loops when dealing with the array lengths, but that doesn't work. I'm completely new to programming, and I know there are WAY easier ways to do this, so if anyone would be able to essentially tell me what I did wrong (and how to fix it to make it work), that'd be fantastic, but also if you have any suggestions for an easier way to write this, that'd also be very much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 1) Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is best fixed by debugging. If you're using Eclipse and don't know how to debug I can help with that.

Comment: I'm using Java, on Dr.Java (I'm not sure if that answered your question; I've never heard of "Eclipse" relative to programming), and what's an "MCVE"?

Comment: Can't you see the link for MCVE in my comment? I never used Dr. Java, but you'll have to learn to debug anyway

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use "<" in your loop. The length of an array equals the number of elements. Because the index of an array starts from 0, the last possible index is length - 1.

When iterating over an array `langs`, always use

```
for(int i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) { ... }
```

or in case you want to iterate backwards

```
for(int i = langs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

The same goes for your `j`variable. If you don't use it anywhere and just want to do the same thing say `n` times. You need to iterate from 0 to `n-1` or from 1 to `n`.

Comment: Even when the for loop starts at zero? I got rid of all the "<=", and it still gives the same error.

Why are the brackets to the right of the loops in your example? I tried putting "{...}" in and it doesn't compile. (I'm literally an absolute beginner with programming; I have no idea what's going on.)

Comment: The `...` is because I don't want to write your entire code again. The brackets define the scope of what needs to be done in one iteration. The focus is on how to make a correct for-loop, not on what needs to be done in the loop. In order to solve your error, you will need to provide some code that we can compile and maybe the stack trace of your exception...

Comment: Ah, I see. I did fix all the loops to look like your example, though, and it still gives me the same error message. It's compiling just fine (now that I know what the "{...}" is), and it did when I posted the above code, too, it just continues to give me the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error, and I have no slight idea where that could be happening. Every loop starts at zero, I've tried "<=" and "<"... It won't even go finish the first loop when I put in a System.out.println("DUR"); to see if it goes through, even though I made the exact same kind of loop earlier in the code and closed it.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the error to your question?